# Rails - model attribute as a variable in function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think it is really basic question, but I cannot find solution.

I have simple help method:

```
def getProperNutrientValue(meal)
    result = 0
  if meal.ingredients.empty?
    result
  else
    meal.ingredients.each do |i|
      result += (i.quantity * @meal.products.find(i.product_id).calorific) / 100
    end
    result
  end
end
```

Where "calorific" is an attribute in Product model.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :meals, :through => :ingredients

  validates :calorific, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
  validates :water, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
```

I want to DRY this function, and set attribute as a variable. Then I will be can use this function for example for water attribute.
So I want to achieve something like that:

```
def getProperNutrientValue(meal, attribute)
    result = 0
  if meal.ingredients.empty?
    result
  else
    meal.ingredients.each do |i|
      result += (i.quantity * @meal.products.find(i.product_id).attribute) / 100
    end
    result
  end
end
```

But of course it doesn't work... How can I fix it?

Comment: But how can I get access to chosen attribute? By dot it doesn't work. Maybe something like this: #{attribute}, but it doesn't work too. Do you understand my problem?

Comment: Use [`instance_variable_get`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get) or [`send`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `send(method_name)` method. I don't understand the logic behind using `@meal` variable. Either way there are some options to improve your code, for example:

```
def getProperNutrientValue(meal, attribute)
  result = 0
  meal.ingredients.each do |i|
    result += (i.quantity * @meal.products.find(i.product_id).send(attribute).to_i) / 100
  end
  result
end

getProperNutrientValue(meal, :calorific)
```

Comment: Yes, it looks much cleaner. I've just changed, thanks :)